# Android src/main/java folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to android and android studio. The project i'm currently working on has src/main/Java and all the java stuff are under this folder. Also there is a module in the project with the same hierarchy. I was wondering if i can change this structure ? Is this structure imposed by android studio? by gradle? 
I would like to remove the "main/java" part and move all my code under the "src" folder. (org,com and etc will move two levels up)
Is there anything that will keep me from doing that ?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec%3asource_sets

Answer (score 2):

This is the default structure for Gradle Android projects.

You can change it with the `sourceSets` thingy (I am not up-to-date with the Groovy typology ;) ) :

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```

However, I encourage you to keep the standard structure, as it is quite handy when you start using more advanced features like [variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants).

You can find more info in the [official documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure).

Comment: This absolutely makes sense. But my problem is the app i have is a Cordova app and in order for me to be able to use the CLI to upgrade cordova or install plugins, i would have to move the folders under src and get rid of the main/java folder.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start a new project in Android Studio it automatically creates the environment for the app to make it run easily on OS. **main** folder inside **src** folder, keeps all the main component of your android app. It keeps all your java files in **java** and resource files in **res**. **main** also keeps **Android Manifest**. So in short this is the correct and preferred way for the environment of Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

I also would recommend to keep the structure as it is.  As you progress with Android development, you start using `buid variants`. It means that you'll have a separate set of resource files (e.g. activity layouts, graphics, config files in xml, etc) + source code for different setups, e.g. when you are debugging or when you are building and testing your application as part of an automated build/test on a CI server or when you are building it normally for a release.

In that case, you'll have `debug`/java and `debug`/res + `main`/java and `main`/res. `main` and `debug` are samples of differnt build variant names, you can have as many build variants as you wish (e.g. `release`, `ci`, etc). The `res` directory here stands for `resources`. This directory doesn't get compiled and is shipped with your APK. `java` directories contain source code (and get compiled). Mixing this things up causes error and if you manage to do that and compile, it just makes your project structure unscalable.

All in all, the structure makes sense in my opinion and is made with project expansion in mind. I would keep it as it is.

Comment: This absolutely makes sense. But my problem is the app i have is a Cordova app and in order for me to be able to use the CLI to upgrade cordova or install plugins, i would have to move the folders under src and get rid of the main/java folder.

Comment: Thats how cordova CLI project is structured.